# Multinomial equivalence test?

Tags: chi-squared-test, multinomial-distribution, contingency-tables, equivalence

I was wondering if there is any statistical equivalence test (in r or python) for multinomial data "a contingency table (4x4)" to know whether the observed and the expected values are equivalence?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, there is one. Please, look at my papers https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2907258 and  https://www.researchgate.net/publication/312481284_Testing_equivalence_of_multinomial_distributions.
The implementation is also available on github. 
Do not hesitate to ask me if any questions occur.

Comment: Please add context to links so the answer is self contained and links only provide further information. https://stats.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I scanned your paper, thanks! and I get some of it, but the details are beyond my grasp. In a separate problem I'm treating a Benford distribution with only 12 data points, as a multinomial distribution with 12 bins, and the I Monte Carlo the expected values. From there I'm able to find out where the data I have would fall, in terms of probability that they are indeed Benford distributed. Is that similar to what you are doing?